# MySql - 10 (very) similar tables or 1 table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

tl;dr at the bottom.

So, I have an application with roughly the following schema:

```
`budget`hasMany =>
   `item1`
   `item2`
    ...
   `item10`
```

Now, this 10 items share a set of **23 fields** that match in all the 10 of the items. At least other **20 fields** are shared in 7 or more items.
This came like this, in retrospective it was idiotic but at the moment it seemed the right thing.

So, with this into mind, I thought: why the hell not make 9 tables dissapear, make 1 table that contains the all the fields from all the items, given that a lot are shared anyway.

What would I gain? Lots of code would dissapear. Lots of tables would dissapear. Retrieving a **budget** with all it's item would require only a join with a single table, instead of 10 joins.

My doubts come from the fact that this new **table** would have around 80 columns. All small columns, storing mostly integers, doubles or small varchars. Still, 80 columns strikes me as a lot. Another problem is that in the future, instead of having 10 tables with 1kk records each, I would have 1 big table with 10kk records.

So, my question is: Is it worth changing in order to remove some redundancy, reduce the amount of code and enchance the habilities to retrieve and work with the data?

**tl;dr** Should I combine 10 tables into 1 table, considering that the 10 tables share a lot of common fields (but still the new table will have 80 columns), in order to reduce the number of tables, the amount of code in the app and enchance the way I retrieve data?

Comment: Yes ... that seem to be the feasible way

Comment: In spite of the new table with 80 fields, which won't be always used?

Comment: A `Item` table w/ shared attributes.  An `attribute` table and an `Item_attribute` table that lists what additional attributes associate to the item and an `Item_attribute_value` table which shows the values of the attributes for those items.  This way you have 4 tables.  1 table that contains the common attributes for all `item`s and then an `attribute` table listing those not shared, `Item_attribute` which shows which items have which attributes and `Item_attribute_values` which show the values assigned to the attribute for that item.  scales well and only 4 tables.

Comment: like data should be stored in the same table.  This way you're not repeating data and tables.  millions of rows in a rdbms is trivial.  Thousands of tables in a RDBMS isn't as trivial. Databases scale w/data not w/ tables (unless you need to partition tables due to size of a table 100's of millions/billions of records.)

Comment: In pseudo code, how would I go about bringing a bugdget with all the items with all it's attributes?

Comment: Please, no hand-waving.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, which might not be a lot, it is optimal to split up a database into singular pieces (as it currently is). It is called to normalize the database ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database").

It limits the Errors that might happen to the database and makes it less risky to change things through updates etcetera as well as better if you want to insert one item but not another (if you only had 1 table all others would be null and you would always have to go back and fetch info etc. which will make the insert statements harder).

If you will always have all 20 items inserted at a time and always do queries based on all of them (no advanced computation on singular items) then it might be reasonable to put everything into one table. But if you want to insert only a couple of items and you then want to make more complex computations I would advice you to keep them separated and linked through some kind of Customer_Id or w/e

Comment: Those common 20 items are always present. Anyway, the problem is that I have repeated code in a way. It's like a have a table to store chairs, another to store tables, another to store sofas. When I could be having one single table to store furniture specifying the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

@yBrodsky ,  as example you should create a table for furniture that will store furniture name, id and description. And another table that would store its attributes with furniture id.

Furniture table will have colums id, furniture_title, description.
And 
Other table will have
id, furniture_id, attribute_key, attribute_value

Comment: I have thought about it, doesn't convince me. Looks like a hack to imitate a schemaless database like mongodb. Have you got any personal experience doing this?

Comment: Yeah, I am using that in my current project. @yBrodsky